# Is there a way to half tab?

Tags: java, arrays, tabs, 2d

I am printing a multiplication table but it comes out messing looking.

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24
 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36
 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48
 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60
 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 66 72
 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70 77 84
 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80 88 96
 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 99 108
 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120
 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 110 121 132
 12 24 36 48 60 72 84 96 108 120 132 144
```

When i Tab it the data overflows to the next line in CMD. 
is there a half tab that can pad the data and make it more structured looking, or at least a way to make it look better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `System.out.printf` to allocate a fixed number of characters for each digit. For instance

```
System.out.printf("%4d", n);
```

will show the value of n right-justified in a four-character field.

Comment: perfect! We had done a similar, operation with doubles and decimal lengths. I didn't realize the same could be applied for this too.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are doing. And I know what you are trying to acheive. But unless you use "spaces" in incriments of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 = tab then you will not be able to "half" a tab. alternatively, you could just go into your cmd properties and make the window size wider.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check to see how many characters your number takes up and subtract that from a set number of padding spaces you insert after you print your number. i.e.

> I use 8 space padding. The number 123 has 3 characters therefore I
>   will pad 5 spaces. The number 12 has 2 characters so I will pad with 6 spaces etc.

Code might look something like:

```
int maxPadding = 8;
int[] listOfNumbers = {1, 11, 111, 2, 22, 222};

for (int number : listOfNumbers){

    System.out.print(number);    

    int numberOfWhitespaces = maxPadding - int.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfWhitespaces; i++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```